# C : reversed array only prints when explicitly looped through

Tags: arrays, c, printf

I am 'saving' the reverse of an array into a new array.
Example:

> array A = abc

> array B = cba

The below code is my solution. The new reversed **array B** does not print unless it is explicitly looped over. Both **fprint %s** and **fprint %c** on individual elements print white space. What is causing this?

Note: Function takes a number and converts to a string first.

```
int reverse(int x){
    int len = int_length(x); //Functions works, gets the length
    len++; //add room for \0
    char *num = (char *)malloc(len * sizeof(char));
    char *ans = (char *)malloc(len * sizeof(char));
    snprintf(num, len, "%d", x); //Turn the numbers into a char array
    printf("%s\n", num);
    
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        ans[i] = num[len-(i+1)];
    }

    
    for(i = 0; i < len; i++) {
     printf("%c\n", ans[i]);  //PRINTS FINE
    }
    
    printf("\n%c\n", num[0]);
    printf("%c\n", ans[0]); //NOTHING PRINTS
    printf("%s\n", ans); //NOTHING PRINTS

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And notice that you can use [`snprintf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) to determine the actual size needed for a string to be created.

Comment: Lastly, the "standard" way to solve problems like yours is to use a *debugger* to step through the code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values.

Comment: you're increasing the len to account for the nul terminator, now the nul terminator is in the mix and corrupts your reversed string by making it empty, unless you print it char by char

Comment: `char *num = (char *)malloc(len * sizeof(char));` should be: `char *num =malloc(len  + 1);`  Cast is wrong for `C` (not for ~C++`), and `sizeof(char)` is always == 1, by definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
len++; //add room for \0
char *num = (char *)malloc(len * sizeof(char));
char *ans = (char *)malloc(len * sizeof(char));
```

that's good to add 1 to the length, but then *don't use that number as the actual string length*

Without debugging it, my guess is the nul terminator winds up at the *start* of the reversed string, making it empty when printed as a string (but showing up okay when you're forcing all characters to be printed beyond the ill-placed nul terminator)

I would *not* change `len`, then explicitly add 1 when allocating:

```
char *num = malloc(len+1);
char *ans = malloc(len+1);
```

(and of course drop the usual redundancy: don't cast a pointer from `malloc`, don't multiply by `sizeof(char)` since it's always 1)

Comment: This worked, I also had to do: snprintf(num, len + 1, "%d", x); Thanks all